# NILauncherView Background Colour

Tags: three20, nimbus-ios, uibackgroundcolor

I'm trying to set the background image of a NILauncherViewController included with iOS NimbubKit (update of the three20 kit).

I've tried
self.launcherView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]];

And self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]];
self.launcherView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

But neither work.

Nor does adding a UIImageView as a subview to the viewController and making the launcher view clear.

Yes the images has the correct name.

**Edit**

If anybody needs to know how to fix this I simply made a UIViewController and added a NILauncherView as a subview and then copied the delegate/datasource methods from the NILauncerViewController

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the view property for the NILauncherViewController is not a NILauncherView. To access the NILauncherView instance just do something like:

```
NILauncherView *view = [controller.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
```

And you can then set the background color with:

```
view.backgroundColor = ...
```